# Emulator: PANIC: Broken AVD system path. Check your ANDROID_SDK_ROOT value [C:\android-sdk]

Tags: android, android-studio

I have been having this problem for a couple of days now, and nothing seems to work... I have added the destination of the sdk to the environment variables under ANDRIOD_HOME and ANDROID SDK ROOT and it still won't work... I have just started app development and without Android studio I'm stuck...

1. what should I do to fix the problem?
2. where else can I run code in order to start learning how to code apps? (not a tutorial, but just an emulator that I can run my code through it)

Answer (score 0):

I'm struggling with this problem too, currently I'm using [Genymotion](https://www.genymotion.com/fun-zone/) as emulator. It's mainly for businesses but you can register for personal use only.